# Filtering fb.api queries on returned field values

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I can query for the picture,location and privacy fields/connections of a users Facebook event with the following FB.api input:

```
me/events?fields=picture,location,privacy
```

I would like to be able to filter the response so I only get events where privacy="SECRET". I tried a few different versions of the FB.api input below and it just returned the normal event list. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
me/events?fields=picture,location,privacy&privacy="SECRET"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not (yet?) possible with Graph API, you should filter results manually.

With `FQL` this can be done like this:

```sql
SELECT eid, pic_big, location, privacy FROM event
  WHERE privacy = 'SECRET' AND eid IN (
    SELECT eid FROM event_member WHERE uid = me()
  )
```